# how to properly pass context between methods to use database repository?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, architecture, software-design

Ok this is a bit more theoretical question.

I have `PlayerRepository`. This is a class that is used to make actions on my SQLite database. I've implemented there actions like `select`, `insert`, `update` etc.

```
public PlayerRepository(Context context) {
    super(context, com.fixus.portals.model.Player.class);
    open();
}
```

`super` in constructor is cause `PlayerRepository extends Repository` which is also my class. The most important part of `Repository` is this one

```
public class Repository<T> {
protected static SQLiteDatabase db = null;
protected static MainHelper helper = null;
protected Context context;
private Class<T> type;

public Repository(Context context, Class<T> classz) {
    this.type = classz;
    this.context = context;
    if(helper == null) {
        helper = new MainHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    } 
}

public static void open() {
    if(db == null) {
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
}
```

As you can see when I create the repository I'm opening DB if it wasn't open before. To do that I need to pass the `Context` of the application/activity. That *is not a problem*.

BUT sometimes I want to use my repository out side of an activity. In some kind of tool class that need to get data. So I have two ways that I can think about

1. I get the data in activity and pass it to my tool class/method so I don't need to use repository in it. This is not very flexible
2. I need to pass context to my tool class/method. But that means that every kind of operation need to receive a context and I'm not sure this is a good way

Am I missing something ? is there any better way to handle it ?

Answer (score 2):

You always need a Context to access the SQLite database so what u could do is change the constructor of that specific tool class and pass a new instance of *PlayerRepository* as a parameter. This prevents your tool class of needing a context itself.

Imo if u have multiple classes using the database best approach is to create a new class whose only job is doing database actions and put all the needed action inside that one.

Just create an object of this database class with the Context of the current activity the to *Tools* and *PlayerRepository* constructors. This way neither your *PlayerRepository* or *Tools* classes need Context and both can make actions on the database.
Even if you should really need Context in *PlayerRepository* it is always best to keep all database related functions centralized in a single class.

Comment: so instead of passing context to repository to create database connection in your solution I should create a class that will establish database connection and pass it as param to repository and tools class. Do I understood you corectly ?

Comment: Yes. That way you put your insert and get queries in the database class and just call `myDatabase.myFunction()`

Comment: Repository is a database class. Each repository for each model. Making one big database calss isn't a good idea IMO. But when I combine repositories with database class that will open/close database and make this object global for whole application thatn I can write indipediant classes and tools. That is imo a good aproach

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question but still i'll write for those like me who will pass by this in future.

In order to get rid of the context problem with repository pattern used for accessing database you can implement DI (**Dependency Injection**) pattern in your project. There are many reasons to do such and that question illustrates one of them.

If you implement DI you would have **only one** instance of database repository amongst the entire module (or app). This instance would be created in a class which has context, and injected to those classes where needed.
One of the simpliest approaches for using DI is to use Dagger 2 library. All of the related information you could find on their site.